# Passport and Node.JS Structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using a MEAN stack and looking to integrate Passport into it.  However, I am not entirely sure how I should structure it.  I eventually want to include several Strategies, but lets start with Google.

In my routes.js file I have:

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));

app.get('/auth/google/return', passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/',
                                failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

That makes sense.  But where should I put the GoogleStrategy() constructor/Success Callback code, in my top level server.js? Let's say I have 5 different strategies, should they all go in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our app we created a separate `passport.js` file with all of our social sign up strategies as well as a separate route file, here's how our Google looks:

`app.js`

```
var social  = require('./routes/social.js')
..

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/signup', failureFlash: true}), social.googleCallback);
```

`passport.js` (located in the root)

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
    config = require('./config');
var socialAuth = config.socialAuth; //contains keys

module.exports = function(passport) {
    /*DEFINE LOGIN STRATS HERE*/
    //GOOGLE+
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: socialAuth.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: socialAuth.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: config.callbackDomain + "/auth/google/callback",
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            //code for strat here
            return done(null, userDoc);
       }
    });
}
```

`social.js` (route)

```
exports.googleCallback = function(req, res) {
    //do stuff with the return from passport
}
```

It works pretty well for managing each type of strategy you want and is pretty easy to add on to.

Comment: Thanks!  Of course, I just found out that the passport-google no longer works for new implementations.  Will have to move on to Google+ Sign in.